# Install Laravel 8 without Jetstream

Tags: laravel, vue.js, tailwind-css, laravel-jetstream, inertiajs

Is there any chance to install Laravel 8 without Jetstream? I want to use Laravel 8 + Inertiajs + Vue.js + Tailwind. Unfortunately Orchid admin panel compatible just with Laravel 8; that's why I have to use Laravel 8.

Comment: Did you actually check the Laravel documentation on this topic? It clearly states it's not required to use Jetstream. You might just need to do some more frontend coding yourself. So the answer is: yes, you can install laravel without Jetstream.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can install laravel 8 without Jetstream, Jetstream is used for Auth, if you decide to create your auth by yourself you are free, or you can use [Laravel Breeze](https://github.com/laravel/breeze) if you are anti-Jetstream for Auth

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel nameofprojectt --prefer-dist
```

if I get your question very well, that will just install a laravel project without Jetstream

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Laravel 8 is by default getting installed without Jetstream.

You can run the following command to start working without Jetstream.

Windows / MacOS:

```
curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
```

Don't forget to repalce "example-app" with the project/directory name you want to give it.

[Laravel installation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation)

Also I recommend to look at Laravel Sail for an easy development server:

[Laravel Sail](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail)

Answer (score 0):

yeah you can

create project laravel

```
$ laravel new blog
```

replace blog by your project name
then go to inertia website, follow the steps and install inertia and vuejs
then install tailwindcss
it's work

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

with composer

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app

cd example-app

php artisan serve
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have composer installed you can use this command line:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel App_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

First Install new Laravel project using the below command:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel YourProject
```

After that install InertiaJS in your project. For more information go to the below link:

https://inertiajs.com/server-side-setup